# Specify metadata cache expiry for Simple.Odata.Client?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, simple.odata.client

Is there a way with Simple.Odata.Client to specify the expiry of the metadata cache?

Within ConfigureServices I'm making an initial request to GetMetadataDocumentAsync to preload the metadata document. I would like to expire the cache after n hours/days to ensure that changes to the resource are reflected in my application.

My current thought is to just set a timer to run ODataClient.ClearMetadataCache(); however I just wanted to check that there isn't something I should be setting when instantiating the ODataClient or when retrieving the metadata document.

Many thanks